# why does returning a function not produce same result as calling code directly

Tags: reactjs, return, ternary-operator

I have this input component

```
<input 
  onBlur={invalidEmail ? 'Your email is invalid' : null}
/>
```

but if I do

```
<input 
  onBlur={errorFunction}
/>

errorFunction = () => {
  return invalidEmail ? 'Your email is invalid' : null
}
```

forgot variable names, assume all coming from state, etc

why would the first one work and the second one not?

Comment: `why would the first one work and the second one not?` 
Are you sure? Because I think second will work, not the first one.

Comment: you need to add  this.errorFunction  in place of errorFunction

Comment: Have you checked the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

`onBlur` expects a callback and you are calling errorFunction and using the return value based on conditions but you have access your component `method` in `render` by using `this` keyword.

> onBlur={ this.errorFunction }

Use following code in your case,

```
  <input 
    onBlur={ this.errorFunction }
  />

  errorFunction = () => {
    return invalidEmail ? 'Your email is invalid' : null
  }
```

Please check [here](https://gist.github.com/santoshshinde2012/a4229d20cb45cec3e4b0846ed6a4a88c) sample code of onBlur for entire react component.

Hope this will help you !!

Answer (score 0):

`onBlur` is an event that is triggered usually by user interaction. You have to pass a function to it, so that the browser can invoke the function with necessary arguments, which you can use at your will

So in the below case, you are actually passing a function reference to `onBlur` which will be called when the event is triggered.

```
<input 
 onBlur={ this.errorFunction }
/>
```

While in the below case, you are passing a string(or null) to `onBlur` and there is nothing to invoke.

```
<input 
 onBlur={invalidEmail ? 'Your email is invalid' : null}
/>
```